# CSS how to set auto length of dotted underline below text

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

In CSS I want have underline as dotted below my text, but text can be short or long by user input and dotted underline must draw until end of line (page A4).

```html
<p style="font-size: 13px;">
I come from ៖ <u style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #999; text-decoration: none; width:100%;"> USA </u>
</p>
```

my code returns only a dotted underline below the underlined text.

Comment: your code looks good...what problem is occuring...?

Comment: You need to improve your question with possible screenshots of what it is exactly you are looking for . Also , the language used to frame your question is incomplete and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In case you want the **whole line** to be underlined,
you need to set the `width: 100%;` for the text so that the border will be drawn to the end of the line.

```css
.underline{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}
```

```html
<p class="underline">
  I come from USA
</p>
```

**2.** In case you want the underline to **start from middle of the text** to the end of the line,
you can use `ul` and `li` to position two parts of text side by side, and then use `width: calc(100% - 100px);` for the part of text that you want the underline to start from. The `100px` is subtracted because of the first part of the text that isn't underlined, so if the no-underline part of the text is longer, you'll need to subtract a bigger portion according to its width.

```css
.underline {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0; 
}

li p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>
      I come from
    </p>
    <p class="underline">
      USA
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```